# Как написать Locale для русского зыка?

Tags: java, locale

Вопрос по локализации проекта. Я могу написать `Locale.UK`, `Locale.FRANCE`, но нельзя написать `Locale.RU`. Как написать `Locale` для русского зыка?

Часть кода:

```
    ResourceBundle bundle;
    Locale locale;

language = input.nextInt();
            switch (language) {
                case 1:
                    locale = Locale.US;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    locale = Locale.RUSSIAN;
                    break;
            }

System.out.println(bundle.getString("languages"));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Константы в `Locale` есть не для всех языков/стран.

Есть несколько способов, как создать локаль для других комбинаций. Смотрите например [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html).

Один вариант - это использовать один из доступных конструкторов:

```
     Locale(String language)
     Locale(String language, String country)
     Locale(String language, String country, String variant)
```

Тут:

- `language` - это 2-ух или 3-ех буквенный код ISO 639 (для русского `ru`)
- `country` - страна по ISO 3166 (Россия - `RU` или `RUS`)